# ¿Como pasar una variable de una funcion a otra en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Cordial saludo compañeros, tengo la siguiente duda respecto a esto, supongamos que tengo las siguientes funciones en uno de mis controladores:

```
public function DatosEstudio(Request $request){

$ConsultaActividades=DB::table('actividades')->select('nombre_actividad')->where('nombre_actividad','like','1%')->get();

}

 public function Recibir(Request $request){


}
```

¿Como podria pasar la variable ConsultaActividades a la otra funcion (Recibir) que esta en el mismo controlador?, en la funcion recibir tambien utilizo request ya que a esta funcion tambien deben llegarle unos datos por formulario. lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera.

```
public function Recibir(Request $request)
{

   $var= $this->DatosEstudio($consultaActividades);
return $consultaActividades;

}
```

Pero me tira error, ¿como deberia hacerse este procedimiento correctamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es correcto por convenciones de diseño llamar a otro método que incluya un Request, en ese orden de ideas los dos métodos deberían comunicarse por otro método private o protected, o yendo un poco más allá, por un modelo, repositorio o servicio, el cuál es llamado desde ambos métodos, o dependiendo de lo que se pretenda hacer, pasar parte del código del segundo método a otra capa más abstracta también.

La primera opción se resume en:

```
protected function getData()
{
    return DB::table('actividades')->select('nombre_actividad')->where('nombre_actividad','like','1%')->get();
}


public function Recibir(Request $request) {
    $var = $this->getData();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfectamente

Comment: Si por ejemplo en ves de ese return, quisiera tomar variables que ya tienen un valor en la otra funcion, como lo harias? por ejemplo que en la funcion datos estudios $ConsultaActividades = $request->input('nombre'); como la llamo en la funcion getdata?

Comment: Se agrega como parámetro de entrada opcional al método getData

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso hay dos operadores para referir a esto, el operador de objeto y el estático, los dos se definen fuera del método.
un ejemplo sencillo seria

```
class SayIt
{

 public $var = NULL;

  public function getData($var)
  {
    return $this->var = $var;
  }

}
// ahora podemos acceder al objeto desde otro archivo previamente llamando al archivo y su localización 
$op = new SayIt();
$op->getData("My name is Outman");
echo $op->var;
```

En este caso hemos utilizado el operador objeto, ver mas detalles [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php)